# How to enable elasticsearch auto-complete return only matching word

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I need to implement auto-complete but I m not sure about the exact strategy. For example I have the following product :

```
Highsound Smart Phone Watch for Android (Gray)
```

So I need when the user starts typing: `"s", "sm", "smar"` , the word `"smart"` or `"smart watch"` to come out rather than the whole phrase: `Highsound Smart Phone Watch for Android (Gray)`

I looked around how google, amazon etc. do it and they dont display the whole matching record, but rather they display either only the word ("smart") or a phrase ("smart watch").

Right now I enable the automcomplete in elasticsearch according to the following link, but it returns the whole name of the matching record.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. You get back what is inside [_source field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html). You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) to get back **only** the word that was matched.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": "sm"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "fragment_size": 1,
        "number_of_fragments": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have used *number_of_fragments : 2* in case there are more than one word starting with *sm*. You can also change *fragment size* according to your needs. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlighted_fragments) on that.You will get something like this, then you can use highlight part for the frontend.

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.6349302,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.6349302,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Highsound Smart Phone Watch for Android (Gray)"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name": [
            " <em>Smart</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: did the solution help?